# Angularjs scope usage in custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a dropdown box by the means of directive **without** creating a separate controller.
Here is my code:

index.html

```
<dropdown option="myoptions" />
```

script.js

```
serviceModule.directive('dropdown',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            options:'='
        },
        template: '<select ng-options="opt in myoptions"></select>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.myoptions = ['1','2','3'];
        }],
    }
});
```

The script neither produces errors nor displays any options in the dropdown.
Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to show more of your code. It is hard to know exactly what is going on. You seem to be trying to pass options into the directive, but then you are also defining them in the directive's controller.

Comment: This is the only code I have. I need to define options inside the directive.

Comment: Where do you define the main app module? Does the main module include the serviceModule? Show the entire index.html please. When you set the options attribute to "myoptions" and then bind it to the isolate scope of your directive you don't need to also define the options in the directive's controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-options` requires a [comprehension expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) of the form `label for value in array`.  And you need to add `ng-model` for `select` to work.

```
template: '<select ng-model="choice" ng-options="opt for opt in myoptions"></select>',
controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $scope.choice;
    $scope.myoptions = ['1','2','3'];
}],
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8a6gwpVnMfvXxZzvQBOs?p=preview